# Ionic: External link in iframe opens in webview (embed youtube player)

Tags: iframe, ionic-framework, youtube-iframe-api

In my ionic (v1.2.4) app there is an embedded youtube player with a link "watch on youtube". If a user clicks this link, youtube website is opened in web view of cordova. It destroys current state of my app. I want to open that link in system's web browser (cordova in app browser plugin).

Same with any link in any iframe (vimeo, soundcloud...)

This link can't be modified with JS from outside the iframe, because cross domain security issues. So i can't update target attribute from `_blank` to `_system`.

Show a dialog `onbeforeunload` is not really an option because it looks ugly :)

Is there a possibility to avoid a page being loaded into the same webview or in the system's web browser?
Breaking links by using iframe's `sandbox` attribute is not an option because it breaks youtube player completely.

Thanks and cheers

ps: i asked this question [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/external-link-in-iframe-opens-in-webview-embed-youtube-player/46074) but couldn't get any helpful information

Answer (score 5):

Thanks thepio for the hint with `allow-intent` and `allow-navigation`. First time i really digged into `cordova-whitelist-plugin`. Finally i fixed my issue on android by setting the correct `allow` attributes in config.xml

```
<!-- Allow links to web pages to open in a browser -->
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

No `allow-navigation` for android. Perfect white label solution. Couldn't find out how to do this on iOS, because iOS needs `allow-navigation` attributes to load iframe content at all.

To fix my issues on iOS in a dirty way, i added this to my config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
  <allow-navigation href="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/*"/>
</platform>
```

Now only the iframe content itself is loaded. Lucky me, every link (watch on YouTube, share, like on vimeo...) inside the iframe is pointing to another domain/subdomain so it is blocked on iOS.

If there are any suggestions, how to create a white label solution for iOS, i am all ears.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is kind of a hardcore solutions for this and should probably be re-written/coded. This solution uses a cordova hook and opens **ALL** links with http or https protocol to a native web browser when they are clicked from a a-tag. For example `<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed">`. This does not only affect iframes but all links.

**Be careful since this might affect some unwanted links in your app**.

I'm running

- Cordova 6.1.1
- Cordova-ios 4.1.1
- Cordova-android 5.1.1

First of all you need to create a hook in the hooks/after_platform_add folder. This will run the hook only when you use `ionic platform add <platform>` or `cordova platform add <platform>`. If you do not have a folder called after_platform_add just create one. Then create a file "01_ios_external_links_hook.js".

Also please read Cordova hooks documentation:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/

There are several ways of defining hooks and creating folders for them seems to be deprecated so you should use the config.xml to attach hooks.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html#via-hooks-directory-deprecated

You can call your file anything and if you are doing it with folders just remember to add access rights to the file. Typically in terminal:

```
chmod +x project/hooks/after_platform_add/01_ios_external_links_hook.js.
```

Please note that this fix is intended only for iOS devices since on android you can handle this with setting `<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />` and setting `<access origin="*" />`. But on the latest Cordova-ios and whitelist-plugin you need to set `<allow-navigation href="*.youtube.com" />` or similar to allow the content of iframe to load on iOS. This will lead to a situation which you described which is that external urls from the iframe will open in the webview.

But back to the solution. This is the code which I have inside the 01_ios_external_links.js file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var replace = require('replace');

if (fs.existsSync('platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVUIWebViewEngine/CDVUIWebViewDelegate.m')) {

  console.log('platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVUIWebViewEngine/CDVUIWebViewDelegate.m - FOUND: fixing');

  replace({
    regex: /.*BOOL shouldLoad = YES;*./g,
    replacement: 'BOOL shouldLoad = YES; NSURL * requesturl = [request URL]; NSString * url = [[request URL]absoluteString]; NSString * documenturl = [[request mainDocumentURL]absoluteString]; if ((navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && ([[requesturl scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[requesturl scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"])) || (([url isEqualToString:documenturl]) && ([[requesturl scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[requesturl scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]))) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requesturl]; return NO;}',
    paths: ['platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVUIWebViewEngine/CDVUIWebViewDelegate.m'],
    recursive: true,
    silent: true,
  });

} else {
  console.log('platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVUIWebViewEngine/CDVUIWebViewDelegate.m  - NOT FOUND');
}
```

Please note that this is a risky operation to be done, but I had no other means of dealing with this problem at the time. The above code searches if there is a file called CDVUIWebViewDelegate.m in the path given and then tries to find a piece of code in there and replace it with another piece of code. But in a nutshell the code above will modify the platform specific code for iOS in the CDVUIWebViewDelegate and add a if statement of the following kind to this file:

```
NSURL * requesturl = [request URL];
NSString * url = [[request URL]absoluteString]; // URL that was requested
NSString * documenturl = [[request mainDocumentURL]absoluteString]; // Main document URL

if ((navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && ([[requesturl scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[requesturl scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"])) || (([url isEqualToString:documenturl]) && ([[requesturl scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[requesturl scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]))) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requesturl]; // forward to application router
    return NO;
}
```

Consider that I'm not a objective-c coder and this is all new to myself also and I made this solution because I did not find any other solutions to my problem which worked. The above if statement could and should be modified to your needs. I have only used this code on development environment and will need to investigate further and improve this method before implementing it to a production environment.

Remember that you need to remove and add the platform for this to take effect. This only occurs when adding a platform as stated above.

But that is it. Now your iOS application will open all urls in a native browser. Hopefully this helps you in the right direction for finding a (better?) solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem and was able to solve with the following code.

```
$('iframe#youtube').get(0).contentWindow.open = function (url) {
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system");
};
```

This code works only on iOS.

Comment: what i did is initial the InAppBrowser object in the constructor and created a function to open the url with '_system'